# Get-AzureAccount not finding accounts when running from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have the following powershell script ("azureaccounts.ps1"):

```
$accountExisted = @(Get-AzureAccount)
Write-Log $accountExisted.Count
```

When I run it from Windows Powershell it finds 5 Azure accounts.
When I run it from CMD it finds 5 Azure accounts. ("powershell azureaccounts.ps1" in cmd)

But when I execute the script from a C# Web Application it doesn't find any account.

With PowerShell API:

```
PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddScript(@"C:\...\azureaccounts.ps1");
var results = powerShell.Invoke();
```

And also with Process object:

```
string sPowershellDir = @"C:\...\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0";
string sDeploymentScriptDir = @"C:\...\azureaccounts.ps1";
string sCommand = String.Format(@"powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File {0}", sDeploymentScriptDir};
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + sCommand);
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = sPowershellDir;
Process oProcess = Process.Start(procStartInfo);
```

One solution would be to execute Add-AzureAccount, but that cmdlet prompts a popup so it can't happen automatically.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute from the command line, you inherit from the previous authentications you did before. You may have authenticated thru a popup that you now want to avoid. With the Web App or the new process, you start from a process that never authenticated to your Azure environment, from a PowerShell perspective.

In order to authenticate in an unattended way, you may want to follow what is described in the documentation at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/. Note that this documentation is based on Azure module V1+.

Still, the idea is the same. 
Note that if you connect in an unattended way from 1 account, the PowerShell script will answer 1. But I suppose you want that script to do other things.